# do relative path in wordpress plugin point to wp-admin path?

Tags: php, wordpress

Actually I saved my image generated by my plugin in a folder `images_uploads` under my plugin folder

when I wrote my plugin where i need to include a relative path. I realise that there is error generated by Firebug. And the file actually point to `wp-admin`. For example:

```
<img src = "./images-uploads/image.jpg">
```

Actually is `<img src = "http://example.com/wp-admin/images_uploads/image.jpg">`
what I want is `<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/images-uploads/image.jpg">`

Can anyone explain why the path is not from the current location of my plugin but instead the loaction of wp-admin. Is there any reference or documentation available???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following in the main plugin file to define its URL and Path:

```php
$this->plugin_url = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
$this->plugin_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
```

Then, print the image like:

```
echo '<img src = "' . $this->plugin_url . 'images-uploads/image.jpg">';
```